# I am getting Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\search-engine\search\search.php on line 23

Tags: php

I am getting  Notice: Undefined variable: i in C:\xampp\htdocs\search-engine\search\search.php on line 23

```
     foreach ($terms as $each) {

         $i++;

         if ($i == 1)
             $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";  
         else
             $query .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

     }
```

Comment: you did not defined the i variable. if defined then please show full code.

Comment: so where is Line 23 ??

Comment: When it is clearly said that is is not defined then did you tried looking at where you have defined $i before doing increment in its value

Answer (score 1):

you have to defined the variable

```
 $i=1;
    foreach ($terms as $each) {



             if ($i == 1)
                 $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";  
             else
                 $query .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";

        $i++;
              }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before use define i variable value or try this

```
foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {        
if ($key == 1)
$query .= "keywords LIKE '%$value%' ";  
else
$query .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$value%' ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First define i variable then use like this

```
$i = 1;         
foreach ($terms as $each) {        
if ($i == 1)
             $query .= "keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";  
         else
             $query .= " OR keywords LIKE '%$each%' ";
          $i++;
     }
```